# Why is there no error when the return value is not catched?

Tags: c++, xcode

As far as I know, the value received from a return type function must be stored where it is called or else it is erroneous.  Please explain how the code below works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>
//Returns a pointer to the heap memory location which  stores the duplicate string
char* StringCopy(char* string) 
{                              
    long length=strlen(string) +1;
    char *newString;
    newString=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*length);
    assert(newString!=NULL);
    strcpy(newString,string);
    return(newString);
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char name[30]="Kunal Shrivastava";
    StringCopy(name);   /* There is no error even when there is no pointer which 
                           stores the returned pointer value from the function 
                           StringCopy */
    return 0;
}
```

I am using c++ in Xcode.

Thank you.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. You may discard return values of functions at any time, for example if you don't care whether a function succeeds or not. In your case, you'll of course leak memory, but a tool like `valgrind` will tell you this.

Comment: ... and in C++ you can use smart pointers that make sure you don't leak even if you ignore the returned object (C++11 `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` for this case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no requirement to use the result of a function call (or any other expression) in C++.

If you want to avoid the memory leak potentially caused by returning a dumb pointer to dynamic memory and hoping that the caller remembers to free it, then don't do that. Return a [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) type which will automatically clean up any dynamic resources for you. In this case, `std::string` would be ideal; and there's no need to even write a function since it has a suitable constructor.

In general, don't write C if you're writing C++.

Comment: +1, and I'd upvote more if I could: *don't write C if you're writing C++*

Comment: *"dont't write C if you're writing C++"* I would like to tattoo that in the forehead of most of the common people who name themselves ***"C++ programmer"***. C-with-classes dates from the end of the 80's, but most times when I read C++ code of other people I feel like if I'm driving a DeLorean with my friends Doc and Marty.